# How to deny a user to access one of the project from repository

Tags: svn

I creted two repository into a repo. There are different projects into both. All the things are going to work fine. but, i am not able to restrict a user for browsing one of the project.

Content of the /etc/apache2/svn_ACL file is

[groups]
admin = administrator, samir, adoor
development = kamlesh, dhiraj, ravindra, vijay, ajit, amit, deepak, abhi, gautam, sudhir
testing = avinash, meenu
readwritegrp = usera, userb
readgrp = userc

[/]
@admin = rw
@development = rw
@testing = r

@readwritegrp = rw
@readgrp = r

[/new_project/trunk]
@readwritegrp = rw
@readgrp =

@admin = rw
@development =

[old_project/trunk]
@readwritegrp = rw
@readgrp = rw

@admin = rw
@development = rw
@testing = r

[/new_project/konfer-nms]
@testing =
@development =
meenu=

Answer (score 1):

This

```
[/] 
@admin = rw
@development = rw 
@testing = r
```

Is your problem, you are allowing the user read access at the root level, and thus to everything, to overcome this

```
[/]
@admin = rw
@development = rw 
@testing =
```

Then

```
[/project_to_allow_access_to]
@testing = r
```

Comment: When I made changes according to youe suggestion, I got 403- forbidden error. Means when we deniy a group/user to access at root label, the group/user is not able to access [/project_to_allow_access_to]